# Owner couldn't edit the record he created

Tags: profile, salesforce-id, configuration, ownership, custom-profile

I have a custom object Named Education__c. The OWD setting us private and on the profile I have given only Create and Read Permissions. So, when User X creates an Education Record, he is becoming the owner of the record. But the user isn't getting any "Edit" option. 
I assumed that owner will always have the edit permission though the profile level permission for Edit is not given. But I see its not actually happening

Can someone correct me if I am missing anything? Is "Edit" Permission definitely needed on the profile to get the edit permission for owner also?

Comment: Can you look at the `Education__share` record that was created and see what access level was given?

Comment: Yes. Edit from Profile is needed to edit the record, else Edit button will not be visible.

Comment: @Devendra That assertion does not seem to be supported by the [Understanding Sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm#sharing_access_levels) doc: *The record owner is automatically granted Full Access, allowing them to view, edit, transfer, share, and delete the record.*

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Yes, the owner gets full access by sharing (record level) BUT if the User Profile of the Owner does not allow for Edit on the Object itself then they are not going to be able to edit it. Often a point of confusion with the record sharing vs profile security

Comment: @AdrianLarson To replicate this, For one of the custom object I have set the OWD as private. On a profile level set the permission as Create, Read and View All. I have not given edit, modify all permission. I have created one record and on detail Edit button was missing. Once I enable the edit permission on Profile, I am able to see Edit button. Thats why, I concluded that Edit permission on Profile is needed.

Comment: @Devendra You should add an answer...Note however that edit access should work if extended through `Permission Set` in addition to `Profile`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Sure. I have added the answer, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Edit from Profile is needed to edit the record, else Edit button will not be visible.

As mentioned by Adrian, `Edit` access can be granted through `Permission Set` in addition to `Profile`.